# Sylius : Override serializer configuration "Model.Product.yml" to expose more fileds

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm new at Sylius I'm using the Rest API.
My question: How can we override serialize files to expose more files.
for example:

vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Model.Product.yml

When I'm testing by adding some fields as archetype and translations they work perfectly

```
Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product:
exclusion_policy: ALL
xml_root_name: product
properties:
    id:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        xml_attribute: true
    name:
        expose: true
        type: string
    description:
        expose: true
        type: string
    attributes:
        expose: true
        max_depth: 2
    createdAt:
        expose: true
        type: DateTime
    updatedAt:
        expose: true
        type: DateTime
    archetype:
        expose:
        serialized_name: archetypes
    translations:
        expose: true
        serialized_name: translations
virtual_properties:
    getVariants:
        serialized_name: variants
```

How can override this configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You should first create your own bundle that extends the Core one (assuming you are using the Sylius standard edition)

Then Override the Product Model, following http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html --> Should be located in YourBundle\Entity\Product.php

Finally, Create Resources\config\serializer\Entity.Product.yml and do here whatever you want :)

Comment: Not working. Sylius still loads its own config